# Am I modifying my Redux state here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux

I am not sure whether this is modifying my redux state:

```
var tempArray = this.props.currentView.someArray;
    tempArray.push(this.state.inputField);
```

Is the first line copying the contents, or is this creating an actual reference to the props object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var tempArray = this.props.currentView.someArray;
```

will make tempArray reference the array.

`tempArray.push()` modifies the reference.

So yes, it will modify `this.props.currentView.someArray`.

If you don't want to modify your state you could do.

```
var tempArray = this.props.currentView.someArray.slice();
```

Slice won't modify the original array and calling it with no arguments returns a copy of the original array.

Modifying `tempArray` after this will have no effect on `this.props.currentView.someArray`